# Drop down parameter to restrict dataset on a column not in resultset

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report based upon a dataset. In the datasets query my where clause looks something like this

```
TM.term_grp_id in (SELECT distinct term_grp_id from ig_mrvCustomisations.dbo.vw_TerminalsByProfitCentre WHERE store_name = @STORENAME))
```

If I run the report without any further development, I won't be prompted for the @STORENAME value.

Instead, I manually created a parameter and tried to link it to the above value, but because I do not include the store_name value in my resultset, it seems i was unable to restrict on it.

I have created a drop down parameter in SSRS based upon the distinct values in the table above, but I am unable to tie them together.

How do I create a prompt that will restrict on @STORENAME ?

Full Query:

```
--DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
--DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @STORENAME NVARCHAR(800)

--SET @STARTDATE = GETDATE()-1 + '06:00:00:000'
--SET @ENDDATE = GETDATE() + '05:59:59:997'
SET @STORENAME = 'IVY'


select 
(DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()-1 + '06:00:00:000')) as 'Day',
 CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1 + '06:00:00:000') as 'Date',
one.term_grp_name AS 'Terminal Group Name',
one.check_type_name AS 'Check Type Name',
(CASE WHEN LEFT(one.check_type_name,2) = 'EV' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Event?',
LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,5) AS 'T3 Coding',
(CASE WHEN LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,2) = '71' THEN '99500'
    WHEN LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,2) = '72' THEN '99550'
 ELSE '99600' END) AS 'T3 Coding for comps',


LEFT(one.term_grp_name,4) AS 'Department',

(CASE WHEN LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,2) = '71' THEN 1010 
WHEN LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,2) = '72' THEN 1020
WHEN LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,5) = '77700' THEN 1070
WHEN LEFT(one.revenue_category_name,5) = '77750' THEN 6165
ELSE 1090 END) as 'Account',
(CASE WHEN one.revenue_category_name = '' THEN 'Total' ELSE one.revenue_category_name END) AS 'Lookup',

LEFT(one.term_grp_name,4) + ' ' + 
(CASE WHEN one.revenue_category_name = '' THEN 'Total' ELSE one.revenue_category_name END) AS 'Dept/Lookup',




one.revenue_category_name as 'Revenue Category',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.Tax)) + sum(CONVERT(money,one.NetRev)) +  sum(CONVERT(money,one.Grat)) AS 'Net Tender',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.NetRev)) as 'Net Revenue',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.disc)) as 'Discount',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.gross)) as 'Gross Revenue',

(CASE WHEN LEFT(check_type_name,2) = 'EV' THEN 0 ELSE sum(CONVERT(money,one.gross)) END) as 'Gross Rev (excl Events)',

(CASE WHEN LEFT(check_type_name,2) = 'EV' THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CONVERT(MONEY,one.grat)) END) AS 'Gratuity (excl Events)',

(CASE WHEN LEFT(check_type_name,2) = 'EV' THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CONVERT(MONEY,one.tax)) END) AS 'Tax (excl Events)',




sum(CONVERT(money,one.Tax)) as 'Tax',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.Grat)) as 'Gratuity',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.SC)) as 'Service Charge',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.Tip)) as 'Tip',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.Covers)) as 'Covers',
Sum(CONVERT(decimal(30,2),one.avecover)) as 'Average Cover',
sum(CONVERT(money,one.Checks)) as 'Checks',
CONVERT(decimal(30,2),(sum(one.NetRev) / nullif(sum(one.Checks),0))) as 'Average Check'


from

(select 
sum(CSD.sales_gross_amount - CSD.discount_amount) as 'NetRev',
sum(CSD.sales_gross_amount) as Gross,
sum(CSD.discount_amount) as Disc,
sum(CSD.gratuity_amount) as Grat,
sum(CSD.service_charge_amount) as SC,
sum(CSD.tip_amount) as Tip,
sum(CSD.tax_amount) as Tax,
sum(CSD.num_covers) as Covers,
(sum(CSD.sales_gross_amount - CSD.discount_amount) / nullif(sum(CSD.num_covers),0)) as 'AveCover',
0 as Checks,
'' as revenue_category_name,
TGM.term_grp_name,
CTD.check_type_name

from ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NoLock)

join it_cfg..Terminal_Master TM (NoLock) on TM.term_id = CSD.tendered_terminal_id
join it_cfg..Term_Grp_Master TGM (NoLock) on TGM.term_grp_id = TM.term_grp_id and TGM.ent_id = 1
join ig_dimension..Check_Type_Dimension CTD (NoLock) on CTD.check_type_dim_id = CSD.check_type_dim_id

where CSD.transaction_data_id in
(select transaction_data_id
from ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NoLock)
join it_cfg..Terminal_Master TM on TM.term_id = CSD.tendered_terminal_id
where tendered_date_time between GETDATE()-1 + '06:00:00:000' and GETDATE() + '05:59:59:997'
and TM.term_grp_id in (SELECT distinct term_grp_id from ig_mrvCustomisations.dbo.vw_TerminalsByProfitCentre WHERE store_name = @STORENAME))
and CSD.tendered_terminal_id <> 0
and CSD.void_state <> 2

group by TGM.term_grp_name, CTD.check_type_name

union all

select 
sum(CRC.gross_sales_amount_tax_included - CRC.discount_amount_tax_included) as 'NetRev',
sum(CRC.gross_sales_amount_tax_included) as Gross,
sum(CRC.discount_amount_tax_included) as Disc,
0 as Grat,
0 as SC,
0 as Tip,
0 as Tax,
0 as Covers,
0 as 'AveCover',
0 as Checks,
RCD.revenue_category_name,
TGM.term_grp_name,
CTD.check_type_name

from 
ig_business..Check_Revenue_Category_Detail CRC (NoLock) 
join ig_dimension..Revenue_Category_Dimension RCD (NoLock) on RCD.revenue_category_dim_id = CRC.revenue_category_dim_id
left join ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NoLock) on CRC.transaction_data_id = CSD.transaction_data_id
join it_cfg..Terminal_Master TM (NoLock) on CSD.tendered_terminal_id = TM.term_id
join it_cfg..Term_Grp_Master TGM (NoLock) on TGM.term_grp_id = TM.term_grp_id and TGM.ent_id = 1
join ig_dimension..Check_Type_Dimension CTD (NoLock) on CTD.check_type_dim_id = CSD.check_type_dim_id

where CRC.transaction_data_id in (select transaction_data_id
from ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NoLock)
join it_cfg..Terminal_Master TM on TM.term_id = CSD.tendered_terminal_id
where tendered_date_time between GETDATE()-1 + '06:00:00:000' and GETDATE() + '05:59:59:997'
and TM.term_grp_id in (SELECT distinct term_grp_id from ig_mrvCustomisations.dbo.vw_TerminalsByProfitCentre WHERE store_name = @STORENAME))

Group By
RCD.revenue_category_name,
TGM.term_grp_name,
CTD.check_type_name

union all

select 
0 as 'NetRev',
0 as Gross,
0 as Disc,
0 as Grat,
0 as SC,
0 as Tip,
0 as Tax,
0 as Covers,
0 as 'AveCover',
COUNT(distinct(CSD.check_number))as Checks,
'' as revenue_category_name,
TGM.term_grp_name,
CTD.check_type_name

from ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NoLock)
join it_cfg..Terminal_Master TM (NoLock) on TM.term_id = CSD.tendered_terminal_id
join it_cfg..Term_Grp_Master TGM (NoLock) on TGM.term_grp_id = TM.term_grp_id and TGM.ent_id = 1
join ig_dimension..Check_Type_Dimension CTD (NoLock) on CTD.check_type_dim_id = CSD.check_type_dim_id

where transaction_data_id in (select transaction_data_id
from ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NoLock)
join it_cfg..Terminal_Master TM on TM.term_id = CSD.tendered_terminal_id
where tendered_date_time between GETDATE()-1 + '06:00:00:000' and GETDATE() + '05:59:59:997'
and TM.term_grp_id in (SELECT distinct term_grp_id from ig_mrvCustomisations.dbo.vw_TerminalsByProfitCentre WHERE store_name = @STORENAME))
and (CSD.associated_check_number = 0 and CSD.refund_flag = 0 and void_reason_dim_id = 0)

group by TGM.term_grp_name, CTD.check_type_name
) as one


Group By one.term_grp_name,
one.revenue_category_name, 
one.check_type_name
ORDER BY [Date] asc, [Terminal Group Name] asc
```

Update: When I remove the Declare and set from the beginning of the query I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared and specified the @STREENAME  variable in your code so SSRS has not need to set it, it will always be `'IVY'`

Comment out the following two lines

`DECLARE @STORENAME NVARCHAR(800)`

`SET @STORENAME = 'IVY'`

It should not work.

**NOTE:** Parameter names are case sensistive so the query parameter name `@STORENAME` should match the SSRS parmatername EXACTLY excluding the `@` symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I follow those instructions I get an error 'Must declare the scalar variable @STORENAME' when trying to preview the report in VS. I realised I had to right click the dataset, select parameter and then add STORENAME - then it worked.